# Oracle missing parentheses error

Tags: sql, oracle, parentheses

This is my query

```
SELECT S.sid,
           S.sname,
           M.major
FROM Student S,
     Major M
     WHERE NOT EXISTS(
               (SELECT C.cno
                FROM Courses C
                WHERE S.sid = M.sid
                  AND M.dname = C.dname) EXCEPT
               (SELECT E.cno
                FROM Enroll E
                WHERE S.sid = M.sid
                  AND S.sid = E.sid
                  AND M.dname=E.dname))
```

Why am I getting a  Invalid SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error when they line up?

Comment: `EXCEPT` in the sense? you can use `MINUS` clause if I guess right

Answer (score 3):

`EXCEPT` is an SQLServer Clause and in oracle `MINUS` is used for the same:
Try this:

```
SELECT S.sid,
     S.sname,
     M.major
FROM Student S,
     Major M
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
     (SELECT C.cno FROM Courses C WHERE S.sid = M.sid AND M.dname = C.dname
     )
MINUS
     (SELECT E.cno
     FROM Enroll E
     WHERE S.sid = M.sid
      AND s.sid  = e.sid
      and m.dname=e.dname
     ));
```